# How to grab a time from a string of text in MQL4?

Tags: string, mql4

Trying to grab a time-value from a text of string in **`MQL4`**.

The string

```
string start_time = "From 21:17 03-02-2016 GMT Till 01:17 04-02-2016 GMT";
```

The code I've tried

```
string EndDate = StrToTime( StringSubstr( start_time,
                                          StringFind( start_time,
                                                      "Till "
                                                      )
                                          + 5,
                                          ( StringFind( start_time,
                                                        "GMT",
                                                        StringFind( start_time,
                                                                    "Till "
                                                                    )
                                                        + 5
                                                        ) - 1
                                            )
                                          - StringFind( start_time,
                                                        "Till "
                                                        )
                                          - 2
                                          )
                            );
datetime exptime = EndDate;
```

The current output is as shown

```
2016.02.03 01:17
```

It is grabbing the **`From`** date not the **`Till`** date.

Is there an easier way to do this? Or a way anyone knows how to fix it?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### <sub>Well, let's go step by step:</sub>

---

### Grabbing correctly the "`From`"-part:

```
int startPTR = StringFind( start_time, // __________ "From 21:17 03-02-2016 GMT ...
                           "From "     // __________ |From |.....
                           )           //  points at |F    ^
                           + 5;        //  points    |>>>>5|B after "From " starts ...

                                       //             0         1         2
                                       //             .123456789.123456789.123
int stopPTR  = StringFind( start_time, // __________ "From 21:17 03-02-2016 GMT ...
                           " GMT "     // ________________________________| GMT |..
                           );          // points at _______________________^

string FromTIME = StringSubstring( start_time, // __________ "From 21:17 03-02-2016 GMT ...
                                   startPTR,   // [ 5]
                                   stopPTR     // [21]
                                   - startPTR  //-[ 5]
                                   );          //_________________|21:17 03-02-2016|
```

---

### Correct conversion from `string` to `datetime`

One shall also check the `MQL4` syntax details, as it reports:

> **`StringToTime()`**
> The function converts a **`string`** containing time or date in `"yyyy.mm.dd [hh:mi]"` format into **`datetime`** type.

Principally the same applies to **`StrToTime()`** function. If you are in doubts, why ***New-*`MQL4`** does have two different functions for the same thing, do not ask me, ask MetaQuotes, Inc.

So the **`FromTIME`** string will finally have to be a little bit re-shuffled so as to meet the stardard **`StringToTime()`** function requirements.

```
datetime Exp = StrToTime(  StringConcatenate( 
                        /* YYYY            */ StringSubstring( FromTIME, 12, 4 ),
                        /* .               */ ".",
                        /* MM              */ StringSubstring( FromTIME,  9, 2 ),
                        /* .               */ ".",
                        /* DD              */ StringSubstring( FromTIME,  6, 2 ),
                        /* _               */ " ",
                        /* HH:MM           */ StringSubstring( FromTIME,  0, 5 )
                                              )
                           );
```

Comment: Alright all i did was replace the From to Till and it seemed to work. So thank you for this :)